# View Issue Calling SecondFragment from FirstFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making a simple demo project using `Fragments`, in which i am calling `SecondFragment` from `FirstFragment` on **button** click.

And i called SecondFragment without any issue, but i `getting view of both the Fragments` SecondFragment and FirstFragment

So where i am doing mistake ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new FirstFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

        Button buttonCallSecondFragment;

        public FirstFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container,
                    false);

            buttonCallSecondFragment = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            buttonCallSecondFragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public static class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

        public SecondFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the first fragment, you can do that either by using`replace` or first calling `remove` then `add`

To be able to press the back button add the transaction to the back stack,you do that by calling `addToBackStack(tag)` on your fragment manager. Tag may be null.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding fragment on already displaying fragment in your android app.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
```

Do not add fragment but replace fragment when already one fragment is loaded on activity.

So for implementing that :

Please add your code in OnCreate() and add below code to your click listener :

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

Thank you.!!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to replace fragment you should call replace in place of add :

```
buttonCallSecondFragment = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                buttonCallSecondFragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the fragment so it will come on top of another fragment give background color to rootview of scecond fragment

Answer (score 0):

you can also load that as **Nested fragment**

```
public void addFragB() {
        FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction childFragTrans =    childFragMan.beginTransaction();
        SecondFragment 2ndfrag = new SecondFragment();
        childFragTrans.add(R.id.fragA_LinearLayout, 2ndfrag);
        //childFragTrans.addToBackStack("");
        childFragTrans.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot communicate between fragments like this. You need to communicate between fragments via the container activity.

I suggest, you make a navigation method in your activity and switch/call between fragments from there.

Below is a small snippet:

In your container activity:

```
Fragment fragment;
    public void navigateTo(Fragment newFragment,boolean addToBackStack) {

        this.fragment = newFragment;
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        if(addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        ft.commit();
    }
```

If you are going from Fragment1 to Fragment2 then in your Fragment1 do the following:

```
((YourContainerActivity) getActivity()).navigateTo(new Fragment2(),false); //if you want to add to back stack make 2nd argument true.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    selectedPosition = position;
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    fragment = null;
    fragmentStack = new Stack<Fragment>();
     switch (position) {

         case 0:

             fragment = new  Fragment1();

             break;

         case 1:

             fragment = new  Fragment2();


             break;

    }
     //redirect the screen
     if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        redirectScreen(fragment);
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(title[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
     }
}
```