# onClick never called in a fragment, android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I'm working on an android project using dynamically created fragments, and I struggle to catch the users events...

here-s the incriminate code.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle data = getArguments();
    ArrayList<String> dataList = null;
    if (data != null) {
        dataList = data.getStringArrayList("jsonlist");
    }
    try {
        for(String object: dataList){
            json.add(new JSONObject(object));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    //Layout template

    ViewGroup maingroup= (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
    mainview = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.finallayout, maingroup, false);
    ViewGroup myLayout= (ViewGroup) maingroup.findViewById(R.id.scrollcontentcontainer);

    for (int i = 0; i < json.size(); i++) {
        View  elementlayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.relative, myLayout, false);
        createMainLayout(this.json.get(i), i, elementlayout, myLayout);
        //sur click sur layout

        elementlayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    addShapeAndBottom();
    return mainview;
}
```

The fragment extends OnClickListener in order to catch the events. The user can click on a **Layout**. I have to add that the fragments are both dynamically added.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

And this is what is suppose to happen when I click somewhere:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.scrollcontentcontainer:

                    System.out.print("test");
                    Fragment contentFragment = new CoreFragment();
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainLayout, contentFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;

        default:
            System.out.print("test");
            break;
    }
}
```

The thing is when I'm trying to debug, I'm not even going into the onClick function which seems to be never called. I tried to declare the listener directly like this:

```
setOnClickListener(public void onClick(View v) {...})
```

but it was not working as well. My aim is to display another fragment on a click on a layout, **elementlayout**, which concerns several layout displayed like a list.

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT 1**

xml code. fimallayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

</RelativeLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomcontent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollcontentcontainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and the template layout I want to click which has to go into the scrollcontentcontainer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="#1d010101"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:duplicateParentState="true">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="00c"
                                                                          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/localisation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Unknow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cwp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="0" />


</GridLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftlayout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fa"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temperature"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="gravity"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hr"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Unknow"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fcontainer"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Some layouts are filled will contents and `addShapeAndBottom();
add a footer.`

**EDIT2**

Adding the listener on `onActivityCreated` doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the problem after some days.

It seems that the `ScrollView` was stealing the focus, making the layout inside and outside unable to receive the user's click.

Removing it fix the problem (which was not linked to the fragment, in the end...).

Answer (score 0):

To make layout click-able need to set click-able property of`elementlayout` :

```
elementlayout.setClickable(true);
```

Also set

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

in `R.layout.relative` for all child Views.

Comment: Nothing appears in the log. I will edit the main post with xml files.

Comment: @Virthuss: where is `R.layout.relative` layout?

Comment: Done, it's the second xml file in the edit.
The aim is to use this one as a template by inflating it several times in the scrollview on the finallayout file.
Then by clicking in one of those templates you can access to another fragment with more informations about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace one fragment with the other via an activity. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367531/view-issue-calling-secondfragment-from-firstfragment/32367631#32367631) link. This is the most modular approach to go from one fragment to another.

Comment: My fragments are called in an asynctask, outside of the main activity :/

Comment: The golden rule is to not call fragments directly from other fragments(which you are currently not doing). Just follow the link that i have given, follow that code snippet. It will work.

Comment: I can but since I separated my fragments, my asynctask and my activity into differents classes and also because I add everything dynamically, I would try to keep my architecture... Also the events were aught before I put the view in a fragment

Comment: But my problem is not switching from a fragment to another, it's I can't catch the click/touch events in it

Comment: Yes, your prob is getting the click event of your layout. May i ask, what are you putting into your scrollcontentcontainer dynamically?

Comment: Some buttons and textview for each layout dynamically added ( it's a list of layout, containing elements, with then a footer). Since it's just visual, I would keep the layout as the only element clickable. Then it displays an other fragment with more informations,